# Pandas explode multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DF that has multiple columns.
Two of the columns are list of the same len.( col2 and col3 are list. the len of the list is the same).

My goal is to list each element on it's own row.

I can use the `df.explode()`. but it only accepts one column. However, I want the pair of the two columns to be 'exploded'. If I do `df.explode('col2')` and then `df.explode('col3')`, it results it 9 rows instead of 3.

Original DF

```
col0      col1        col2        col3
1       aa          [1,2,3]     [1.1,2.2,3.3]
2       bb          [4,5,6]     [4.4,5.5,6.6]
3       cc          [7,8,9]     [7.7,8.8,9.9]
3       cc          [7,8,9]     [7.7,8.8,9.9]
```

End DataFrame

```
id      col1        col2        col3
1       aa          1           1.1
1       aa          2           2.2
1       aa          3           3.3
2       bb          4           4.4
2       bb          5           5.5
2       bb          6           6.6
3       cc          ...         ...
```

Update
None of the column have unique values, so can't be used as index.

Comment: Better answer can be found [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67097110/convert-elements-in-lists-to-separate-rows/67097208#67097208). No need to use `set_index` and `reset_index`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could set `col1` as index and apply [`pd.Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html#pandas.Series.explode) across the columns:

```
df.set_index('col1').apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
```

Or:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.explode)


   col1 col2 col3
0    aa    1  1.1
1    aa    2  2.2
2    aa    3  3.3
3    bb    4  4.4
4    bb    5  5.5
5    bb    6  6.6
6    cc    7  7.7
7    cc    8  8.8
8    cc    9  9.9
9    cc    7  7.7
10   cc    8  8.8
11   cc    9  9.9
```

Comment: Thanks, I thin it would give an error because none of the column have unique values, so can't be used as index.

Comment: What do you mean? `col1` isn't unique? That is not a problem, try yourself, a col doesn't have to have unique values so it can be set as index @Imsa

Comment: Updated with the new df @Imsa

Comment: @lmsa it doesn't matter whether your column is unique valued or not, you can still set it as index.

Comment: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` this the error I get when I run the following command. Please advise.

Comment: What version of pandas? Have you tried updating pandas @imsa

Comment: I have Pandas 1.2.0 and I'm getting the same `ValueError`. I actually had a MultiIndex, but I tried dropping it for the sake of reproducibility, but it didn't work either way.

Comment: No need to `set_index` and `reset_index`. Just use `df = df.apply(pd.Series.explode)`. This will explode all the columns with `lists` in your dataframe.

Comment: @MayankPorwal I still get ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: @GM you need to upgrade your pandas.

Comment: @RémyHosseinkhanBoucher You need to upgrade your pandas.

Comment: @MayankPorwal please, i am in pandas                    1.2.4            py38h2531618_0

Comment: same with pandas 1.2.4

Comment: I can confirm just using `df = df.apply(pd.Series.explode)` works in pandas 1.1.5

Comment: `df = df.apply(pd.Series.explode)` works with pandas 1.3.2

Answer (score 8):

I borrowed this solution from other answers (forgot where):

`df.explode(['col2', 'col3'])`.

The advantage: faster than the `apply` solution.

Make sure both col2 and col3 have the same number of elements in cells in the same row.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Note: It requires pandas >=1.3.0