# How to animate a straight in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to visualize the process of fitting a straight line to a 2D dataset.
For every epoch, I have the x and y coordinates of the starting point and the endpoint of the straight. Below is an example image of a dataset with a line (matplotlib).

[image]

I saw that plotly provides an option to animate lines.

[image]

The above plot was created with code similar to this:

```
# this should animate my line
fig_data = px.line(df, x="xxx", y="yyy", animation_frame="epoch", animation_group="name", title="fitted line")

# responsible for the red scatter plot points:
fig_data.add_traces(
    go.Scatter(
        x=xxx, 
        y=yyy, mode='markers', name='House in Dataset')
)
```

The dataframe looks like that:

```
epoch       xxx                                       yyy      name
0       0  [0.5, 4]   [1.4451884285714285, 4.730202428571428]  example
1       1  [0.5, 4]  [1.3944818842653062, 4.4811159469795925]  example
2       2  [0.5, 4]   [1.3475661354539474, 4.251154573663417]  example
3       3  [0.5, 4]    [1.3041510122346094, 4.03885377143571]  example
```

So the line that should be shown in epoch 0 starts from (0.5,1.44) and goes to (4,4.73).
However, no line is rendered. What should I change?

Comment: where does `datapoints_x` and `datapoint_y` come from?

Comment: my bad. fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is with the format of `xxx` and `yyy` in `df`, as they are now they're nested arrays that don't seem to be referenced correctly by `px.line`.

You can use `pd.Series.explode` to "flatten" this data frame (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62801615/11305111)) and then use that as the input to `px.line`.  See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html?highlight=explode) for more info on panda's explode.

Using `xdf=df.set_index('epoch').apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()` will yield:

```
epoch   xxx      yyy       name
0   0   0.5 1.445188    example
1   0   4   4.730202    example
2   1   0.5 1.394482    example
3   1   4   4.481116    example
4   2   0.5 1.347566    example
5   2   4   4.251155    example
6   3   0.5 1.304151    example
7   3   4   4.038854    example
```

Full example with comments:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

data = {'epoch': [0,1,2,3], 
        'xxx': [[0.5, 4], [0.5, 4], [0.5, 4], [0.5, 4]],
        'yyy': [[1.4451884285714285, 4.7302024285714280], 
                [1.3944818842653062, 4.4811159469795925], 
                [1.3475661354539474, 4.2511545736634170], 
                [1.3041510122346094, 4.0388537714357100]],
       'name':['example','example','example','example']}  
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

# now exploding `df`
xdf=df.set_index('epoch').apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()

# now plotting using xdf as dataframe input
px.line(xdf, x="xxx", y="yyy", animation_frame="epoch", color="name", title="fitted line")
```

Note: The raw data for the scatter seems to be missing, but I don't think that's what's in question here.

[image]