# parsing json in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I need to parse this response into a pandas dataframe.

```
  "predictions": [
    {
        "predicted_label": 4.0,
        "distances": [3.11792408, 3.89746071, 6.32548437],
        "labels": [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
    },
    {
        "predicted_label": 2.0,
        "distances": [1.08470316, 3.04917915, 5.25393973],
        "labels": [2.0, 2.0, 0.0]
    }
  ]
```

The end result i am looking for is:

|  | predicted_label | distances | labels |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4.0 | 3.11792408 | 0.0. |
| 1 | 4.0 | 3.89746071 | 1.0 |
| 2. | 4.0. | 6.32548437 | 0.0 |

same for the second predicted_label 2.0.

I tried using:

```
pd.json_normalize(result['predictions'], record_path='distances', meta='predicted_label', record_prefix='dist_')
```

but that will not give me the labels column

Comment: Thank you very much both Henry and Derek O!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming `result` takes the following format:

```
result = {"predictions": [{"predicted_label": 4.0,"distances": [3.11792408, 3.89746071, 6.32548437],"labels": [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]},{"predicted_label": 2.0,"distances": [1.08470316, 3.04917915, 5.25393973],"labels": [2.0, 2.0, 0.0]}]}
```

If you pass `results['prediction']` to `pd.DataFrame`, you will get some rows that are lists because `"predicted_label"` is length 1, while `"distances"` and `"labels"` are length 3:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(result['predictions'])
   predicted_label                             distances           labels
0              4.0  [3.11792408, 3.89746071, 6.32548437]  [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
1              2.0  [1.08470316, 3.04917915, 5.25393973]  [2.0, 2.0, 0.0]
```

To get around this, we can then set `predicted_label` to be the index, then apply `pd.Series.explode` to the other columns (credit goes to @yatu's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62801562/pandas-explode-multiple-columns)), before resetting the index. Since they are lists, they are of type `dobject`, so we can use applymap to change everything to type float.

Set the formatting to 8 digits after the decimal: `pd.options.display.float_format = "{:.8f}".format`

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(result['predictions']).set_index('predicted_label').apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index().applymap(lambda x: float(x))

   predicted_label  distances     labels
0       4.00000000 3.11792408 0.00000000
1       4.00000000 3.89746071 1.00000000
2       4.00000000 6.32548437 0.00000000
3       2.00000000 1.08470316 2.00000000
4       2.00000000 3.04917915 2.00000000
5       2.00000000 5.25393973 0.00000000
```

Comment: FWIW the `set_index` part is unnecessary explode handles "unexplodeable" elements quite well `pd.DataFrame(result['predictions']).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: one problem with the answer is that the returned numbers are now objects. they also have fewer digits. 3.11792408 vs 3.117924.  that prevents the next "join" step that i am trying to accomplish

Comment: That's quite peculiar - let me look into this and see if casting as a string then back to float might be a workaround

Comment: The number of digits are not actually fewer: you can control the formatting with `pd.options.display.float_format = "{:.8f}".format` which will display all 8 digits after the decimal, for example

Comment: I updated the answer - hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

the response seems like a bunch of records
you could parse them one by one, then concat it together:

```
df = []
for dd in response['predictions']:
    df.append(pd.DataFrame(dd))
df = pd.concat(df).reset_index(drop=True) # reset_index if needed.
```