# how to solve pandas multi-column explode issue?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-explode

I am trying to explode multi-columns at a time systematically.
Such that:

[[image: 1]

and I want the final output as:

[image]

I tried

```
df=df.explode('sauce', 'meal')
```

but this only provides the first element ( sauce) in this case to be exploded, and the second one was not exploded.

I also tried:

```
df=df.explode(['sauce', 'meal'])
```

but this code provides

```
ValueError: column must be a scalar
```

error.

I tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62801562/pandas-explode-multiple-columns), and [also this](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/10113). none worked.

Note: cannot apply to index, there are some none- unique values in the fruits column.

Comment: Could you please share your data example instead of picture?

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? You need to update, because passing a list of columns to `explode` was added recently.

Comment: @richardec 1.1.5

Comment: @richardec which version of pandas you'd recommend to install

Comment: @hilo 1.3.5, the latest version ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to pandas 1.3.0 use:

```
df.set_index(['fruits', 'veggies'])[['sauce', 'meal']].apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  fruits veggies sauce meal
0     x1      y2     a    d
1     x1      y2     b    e
2     x1      y2     c    f
3     x2      y2     g    k
4     x2      y2     h    l
```

Many columns? Try:

```
df.set_index(df.columns.difference(['sauce', 'meal']).tolist())\
  .apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  fruits veggies sauce meal
0     x1      y2     a    d
1     x1      y2     b    e
2     x1      y2     c    f
3     x2      y2     g    k
4     x2      y2     h    l
```

Comment: I have 78 columns, indexing might be an issue here...

Comment: It shouldn't be.  Just move all columns not exploded into the index.

Comment: @hilo See updated syntax for many columns.

Comment: It was a very tricky and efficient solution. Thank you for your clean, insightful contribution Scott. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

**Update your version of Pandas**

```
# Setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'fruits': ['x1', 'x2'],
                   'veggies': ['y1', 'y2'],
                   'sauce': [list('abc'), list('gh')],
                   'meal': [list('def'), list('kl')]})
print(df)

# Output
  fruits veggies      sauce       meal
0     x1      y1  [a, b, c]  [d, e, f]
1     x2      y2     [g, h]     [k, l]
```

Explode (Pandas 1.3.5):

```
out = df.explode(['sauce', 'meal'])
print(out)

# Output
  fruits veggies sauce meal
0     x1      y1     a    d
0     x1      y1     b    e
0     x1      y1     c    f
1     x2      y2     g    k
1     x2      y2     h    l
```