# how to change the iterrows method to apply

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code, in which I have rows around 60k. It taking around 4 hrs to complete the whole process. This code is not feasible and want to use apply instead iterrow because of time constraints.

Here is the code,

```
all_merged_k = pd.DataFrame(columns=all_merged_f.columns)
for index, row in all_merged_f.iterrows():
    if (row['route_count'] == 0):
        all_merged_k = all_merged_k.append(row)
    else:
        for i in range(row['route_count']):
            row1 = row.copy()
            row['Route Number'] = i
            row['Route_Broken'] = row1['routes'][i]
            all_merged_k = all_merged_k.append(row)
```

Basically, what the code is doing is that if the **route count** is 0 then append the same row, if not then whatever the number of counts is it will append that number of rows with all same value except the **routes** column (as it contains nested list) so breaking them in multiple rows. And adding them in new columns called **Route_Broken** and **Route Number**.

Sample of data:

```
               routes  route_count
          [[CHN-IND]]            1
[[CHN-IND],[IND-KOR]]            2
```

O/P data:

```
               routes  route_count  Broken_Route Route Number
          [[CHN-IND]]            1   [CHN-IND]       1
[[CHN-IND],[IND-KOR]]            2   [CHN-IND]       1
[[CHN-IND],[IND-KOR]]            2   [IND-KOR]       2
```

Can it be possible using apply because 4 hrs is very high and cant be put into production. I need extreme help. Pls help me.

So below code doesn't work

```
df.join(df['routes'].explode().rename('Broken_Route')) \
      .assign(**{'Route Number': lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1)})

or

(df.assign(Broken_Route=df['routes'],
           count=df['routes'].str.len().apply(range))
   .explode(['Broken_Route', 'count'])
)
```

It doesn't working if the index matches, we can see the last row, Route Number should be 1

Comment: Is the length of the list in `'routes` always equal to the value in `route_count`? (It would seem so, but just to verify.)

Comment: @mozway can you see it?, it will get visible until approved, but below is how data looks like
routes 
[[CHN-IND]] 
[[CHN-IND],[IND-KOR]]

route count: 1   2

Comment: @9769953 yes it always matches

Comment: @freak7 Why are you editing and answering on simpleboi's question?

Comment: You are appending to a dataframe on every loop. This is actually a slow operation because the dataframe is practically recreated on every iteration. Instead, it is more efficient to store everything in a list, then create the dataframe itself at the very end. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929472/improve-row-append-performance-on-pandas-dataframes for more info.

Comment: @mozway added the o/p

Comment: is the content lists or text? [good reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) ;)

Comment: @mozway it is list of lists, nested list

Comment: let us know of efficient it is in real-life ;)

Comment: @mozway can you please check the update 1

Comment: @simpleboi easy fix, temporarily move you index as column with `reset_index`, perform the transform, set again as index with `set_index`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you expect something like that:

```
>>> df.join(df['routes'].explode().rename('Broken_Route')) \
      .assign(**{'Route Number': lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1)})

                   routes  route_count Broken_Route  Route Number
0             [[CHN-IND]]            1    [CHN-IND]             1
1  [[CHN-IND], [IND-KOR]]            2    [CHN-IND]             1
1  [[CHN-IND], [IND-KOR]]            2    [IND-KOR]             2
2                                    0                          1
```

Setup:

```
data = {'routes': [[['CHN-IND']], [['CHN-IND'], ['IND-KOR']], ''], 
        'route_count': [1, 2, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Update 1**: added a record with `route_count=0` and `routes=''`.

Comment: [lazy mode] do you have the constructor to share?[/lazy mode] :p

Comment: Suppose: `{'routes': [[['CHN-IND']], [['CHN-IND'], ['IND-KOR']]], 'route_count': [1, 2]}`

Comment: @simpleboi. Can you check my update please?

Comment: @Corralien checking.

Comment: @freak7. When `route_count == 0`, What is the value of `routes`? An empty list, nan?

Comment: I'd have use more or less the same (with `assign` in place of `join`) +1. I provided an alternative for fun

Comment: @Corralien in that case it will be empty

Comment: @mozway. It's a great answer too. +1.

Comment: @Corralien but likely less efficient, I find it fun though ;)

Comment: @simpleboi. Is it faster? :)

Comment: Here when I thoroughly looked and I saw, in same index I have row with different value and thus it giving wrong route count. So level=0 is not a good idea then also I have column more than 10.

Comment: @Corralien pls suggest help

Comment: @Corralien can you please check the update 1

Answer (score 3):

You can assign the routes and counts and explode:

```
(df.assign(Broken_Route=df['routes'],
           count=df['routes'].str.len().apply(range))
   .explode(['Broken_Route', 'count'])
)
```

*NB. multi-column explode requires pandas ≥1.3.0, if older use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62801562/pandas-explode-multiple-columns)*

output:

```
                   routes  route_count Broken_Route count
0             [[CHN-IND]]            1    [CHN-IND]     0
1  [[CHN-IND], [IND-KOR]]            2    [CHN-IND]     0
1  [[CHN-IND], [IND-KOR]]            2    [IND-KOR]     1
```

Comment: thanks a lot it really helpful too.

Comment: I was looking into this code as well, in same index I have row with different value and thus it giving wrong route count, do we have any fix for this.